# Is it possible to check whether addition of two variables results in overflow?

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation, addition

What I mean is, could I construct a general procedure

```
public bool Overflows<T> ( T a, T b ) 
{
    // returns true or false based on whether
    // a + b overflows
}
```

that I can use like

```
byte b1 = 255, 
     b2 = 1;
Console.WriteLine("Does {0} + {1} oveflow? {2}", b1, b2, Overflows(b1,b2) ? "Yes : "No"); // Answer should be "Yes" here
```

???

I guess in the case of `byte`s I can look at whether `(a+b) < a` and `(a+b) < b`. e.g. I know that `255+1` overflows because the result if `0` which is smaller than `255` and `1`. Or, I can cast them to larger data types and check like

```
return ((int)a + (int)b) > (int)Byte.MaxValue;
```

but that won't work across all numeric types that have an `+` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is to explicitly check for an overflow and catch the relevant exception (pseudocode — see below):

```
public bool Overflows<T> ( T a, T b ) 
{
    {
        // the 'checked' keyword ensures an OverflowException is thrown 
        // as a result of a real integer overflow happening
        c = checked(a + b);  // * with 'T' this won't compile, see below
        return false;
    }
    catch (System.OverflowException e)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, for a generic type parameter `T` the compiler doesn't understand the `+` operator. Two options here:

1. declare all possible versions of the method, i.e. `Overflows(int, int)`, `Overflows(byte, byte)` etc.
2. use type comparison and casts:

   ```
   if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
       int i = checked((int)a + (int)b);
   else if (typeof(T) == typeof(byte))
       byte b = checked((byte)a + (byte)b);
   … etc.
   ```